# How to show a temporally Success Message without using query parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show a success message in a view `SingIn.cshtml` **only one time** after user registration. In order to do it, i was thinking into sending a boolean parameter to the *SingIn Action method* so then the View `SingIn.cshtml` will get it, and then choose if it should show it or not, but since the parameter will appear in the query string (app.com/Account/SignIn?parameter=true), the user can refresh the page and see it again and again or maybe he can type the url and saw it again.So How can i complete my approach without showing the parameter on a query string (app.com/Account/SignIn) ?
This is my Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<Client> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<Client> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<Client> userManager, SignInManager<Client> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View(new SignUpViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(SignUpViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var client = new Client
            {
                UserName = viewModel.Id, FullName = viewModel.FullName, BirthDate = viewModel.BirthDate.Value,
                Email = viewModel.Email
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(client, viewModel.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("SignIn", new {DidHeJustSignUp = true});
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignIn(bool didHeJustSignUp)
    {
        var model = new SignInViewModel {DidHeJustSignUp = didHeJustSignUp};
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model SignInViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sign In";
}

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" method="post">
    @{
        if (Model.DidHeJustSignUp)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                You have been registred Successfully, please Sign In
            </div>
        }
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Id">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Id"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="Password"/>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="ShouldIRememberYou">
        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="ShouldIRememberYou">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TempData` here, anything you put into TempData is discarded after the next request completes.

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    TempData["DidHeJustSignUp"] = true;
    return RedirectToAction("SignIn");
}
```

```
if (TempData["DidHeJustSignUp"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                You have been registred Successfully, please Sign In
            </div>
        }
```